# Media query (Responsive)

Tags: css, media-queries

I got stuck with the responsive of my website. I am not getting the exact device width of samsung s9+ to make it responsive. If I am changing some code then it is reflecting with the other mobile also.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

I am taking help of this website of media queries.
I have tried almost all device width size to get exact device width

Comment: Quote from the mentioned link by Chris Coyier.
"you should never base your breakpoints on devices!!"

Comment: Can you tell us why you need to target this exact device? As @voodoocode suggests, it's a bad idea to style for specific device widths.

Comment: Also, if I reread your description: "If I am changing some code then it is reflecting with the other mobile also"
That's exactly what's responsive design is all about. Media queries should target a group of devices, so they all get affected by the same rules.

Comment: i am using the chrome web design tester. In that i am not getting any reflection of changes in code. I have samsung s9+. tried to check on my phone but its not reflecting.

Answer (score 0):

I found this website to see the media queries for standard devices:

https://www.mydevice.io/